# Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS /dev/sda5 noob

Tags: 20.04

Out of 448GiB of memory, 375GiB memory is taken. However, only about 40GiB is taken up by files in various folders. I've searched for solutions online, how to delete/free up space but to no avail.

sda1 is boot and takes up 512 MiB, while sda2 doesn't use any.

FSTYPE NAME   LABEL   SIZE FSUSED MOUNTPOINT
sda          447.1G
vfat   ├─sda1         512M     4K /boot/efi
├─sda2           1K
ext4   └─sda5       446.6G 366.6G /
sr0           1024M

I've also come across the following. My HP laptop screen started freezing recently:

E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

All suggestions are welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question and include information about your system's partitions. Either open a terminal and type `lsblk -e7  -o FSTYPE,NAME,LABEL,SIZE,FSUSED,MOUNTPOINT`, then copy and paste the output, or take a screenshot from the app `gparted`. Do not put the info in comments, edit your question.

Comment: You are mixing up memory which is ram and hard disk space which is storage. I do not think you have over 400 gig of memory.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the memory by using Disk usage analyser. Clicked on home, HP Ubuntu 20.04 folder and shift deleted the entire content (it was the same zipped file amounting to a couple of hundred GB).

As far as the screen freezing, it was down to the Telegram app. I uninstalled it and reinstalled it. Problem solved. For now.